# iOS 13 URLSessionWebSocketTask Current Connection Status

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, urlsession

I have my `URLSessionWebSocketDelegate` set up and implemented

```
urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?)
```

However, it only seems to hit the delegate if the server makes a proper disconnect. If the connection drops or the server doesn't provide a disconnect code, the delegate function never runs. I've also tried checking the `URLSessionWebSocketTask` properties `closeCode` and `closeReason` before and after the disconnect and they don't change unless the server sends a proper disconnect code.

While I have control over the server and can be sure intentional disconnects have a code, what happens if the network connection dies? Or if the server goes down? I would assume the delegate function *should* still get called.

What's interesting is that my listening function gets an error and the error states the following:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=57 "Socket is not connected" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=[urlomitted], NSErrorFailingURLKey=[urlomitted]
```

So while I COULD manually disconnect the socket if I see error 57, I don't know if that's comprehensive for all the different variations of disconnect.

I think I'm either doing something wrong or it's a bug, but I can't find anyone else with the same issue, so I thought I'd ask before submitting a radar.

Comment: Same here. Have you solved this issue yet?

Comment: It's been so long, I'm not certain if I figured out a workaround or not. I do know that there wasn't a straight up "fix", though. I believe this is the file and the project I was working on regarding this question: https://github.com/mredig/DungeonBattleRoyale-iOS/blob/develop/BSVBattleRoyale/Networking/WebSockets/WebSocketConnection.swift feel free to poke around to see if this approach works for you!

Comment: The error code 57 is defined in the enum `POSIXErrorCode` as case `ENOTCONN`.

Answer (score 7):

Do exactly what I did in the sample it works correctly without any problem.
It manages connection status and when you need to reconnect again it uses connect method to reinit the socket.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class NativeWebSocket: NSObject, WebSocketProvider, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionWebSocketDelegate {
    var delegate: WebSocketProviderDelegate?
    private var socket: URLSessionWebSocketTask!
    private var timeout: TimeInterval!
    private var url: URL!
    private(set) var isConnected: Bool = false

    init(url: URL, timeout: TimeInterval) {
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.url = url
        super.init()
    }

    // do not move create socket to init method because if you want to reconnect it never connect again
    public func connect() {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, timeoutInterval: timeout)
        socket = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: urlRequest)
        socket.resume()
        readMessage()
    }

    func send(data: Data) {
        socket.send(.data(data)) { error in
            self.handleError(error)
        }
    }

    func send(text: String) {
        socket.send(.string(text)) { error in
            self.handleError(error)
        }
    }

    private func readMessage() {
        socket.receive { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure:
                break
            case .success(let message):
                switch message {
                case .data(let data):
                    self.delegate?.webSocketDidReciveData(self, didReceive: data)
                case .string(let string):
                    self.delegate?.webSocketDidReciveData(self, didReceive: string.data(using: .utf8)!)
                @unknown default:
                    print("un implemented case found in NativeWebSocketProvider")
                }
                self.readMessage()
            }
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didOpenWithProtocol protocol: String?) {
        isConnected = true
        delegate?.webSocketDidConnect(self)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?) {
        isConnected = false
    }

    /// never call delegate?.webSocketDidDisconnect in this method it leads to close next connection
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            handleError(error)
        }
    }

    func closeConnection() {
        socket.cancel(with: .goingAway, reason: nil)
    }

    /// we need to check if error code is one of the 57 , 60 , 54 timeout no network and internet offline to notify delegate we disconnected from internet
    private func handleError(_ error: Error?) {
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            if error.code == 57 || error.code == 60 || error.code == 54 {
                isConnected = false
                closeConnection()
                delegate?.webSocketDidDisconnect(self, error)
            } else {
                delegate?.webSocketReceiveError(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has to be the most strange formatting I have ever seen

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is a good way to do it, however both solutions below do capture loss of server/connection events in my code.

a) You could detect it in your WebSocket receive function like this:

```
func receiveMessage() {
        webSocketTask?.receive { result in
            defer { self.receiveMessage() }
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error in receiving message: \(error)")
                let code = (error as NSError).code
                if code == 60 || code == 57 || code == 54 {
                    // deal with error
                }
            case .success(let message):
                switch message {
                case let .string(string):
                    // deal with strings message
                case let .data(data):
                    // deal with data message
                @unknown default:
                    // deal with unknown message
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

b) Or you can add an urlSession instance method to your `URLSessionWebSocketDelegate` which captures general loss of server/connection error.

```
extension BlipSocket: URLSessionWebSocketDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didOpenWithProtocol protocol: String?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isConnected = true
        }
    }
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isConnected = false
        }
    }
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError: Error?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.connectionError = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I manually disconnect websocket task like `webSocketTask.cancel(with: .goingAway, reason: nil)`, **both** `urlSession(..didCloseWith..)` and `urlSession(.. didCompleteWithError..)` are invoked. Probably because `receive` recursive function is running. Is there a way to gracefully shutdown websocketTask?

Answer (score 1):

You also can implement `urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)` which is an URLSessionDelegate. This fires an URLSessionError when the connection fails. I'v used the following implementation.

```
 func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    guard let error = error as? URLError else { return }
    
    switch error.errorCode {
    // offline, timedOut
    case -1009, -1001:
        delegate?.didDisconnect(
            reasonCode: UInt16(URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode.abnormalClosure.rawValue),
            error: error)
    default: break
    }
}
```

this fires up after 60 seconds from the first failed request. Setting up `URLSessionConfiguration` with a shorter timeout doesn't seem to work, it always fires after 60 seconds, which sucks. Hope this helps, a better solution would be great